# Generate records, based on a given minimum and maximum range. SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am self educating myself with SQL, and I am trying to generate records, based on a given minimum and maximum range.

For example,

I have...

```
PCID       PCName       PCLowestStock       PCHighestStock         PCAllStock
______________________________________________________________________________
DEL        DELL PC            1                  3                   ?
HPP        HP PC              1                  2                   ?
```

I want...

```
PCID            PCName       PCLowestStock       PCHighestStock         PCAllStock
__________________________________________________________________________________
DEL00001        DELL PC           1                  3                   00001
DEL00002        DELL PC           1                  3                   00002
DEL00003        DELL PC           1                  3                   00003
HPP00001        HP PC             1                  2                   00001
HPP00002        HP PC             1                  2                   00002
```

How exactly would I go about doing this. Please bear in mind, I am self learning, and I am new here.

Thanks

Comment: Which of the three DBMSes you've added as tags (MySQL, SQL Server, SQLite) are you actually using?

Comment: @IMSoP, sorry I'm using MySQL at the moment. I'm running on my own local server

Comment: Are you looking for a script of some kind to insert a series of records in a loop?